# how to resolve Error 193:%1 is not a win32 application in dev c++?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

unable to compile even the hello world programe

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
     int main(){
    cout <<"hello world";
    system("pause");
    return 0;

    }
```

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: You're running a 64 bit application in 32 bit workstation?

Comment: Error is "Error 193: %1 is not a valid win32 Application"

Comment: i am runing a 64 bit machine

Comment: What compiler and IDE versions do you use

Comment: @MauriceRandomNumber dev c++

Comment: devc++ is an IDE not a compiler, did you install a compiler? some installers for devc++ include gcc, some don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dev ++ clearly compiles to 16 bit architectures and they are deprecated and unsupported since exactly Windows Vista. So you clearly have to use a different compiler.

Comment: that just confirms my answer obviously, newer versions of windows can't run 16 bit.

Comment: it works on same version of windows 10 on my friends machine

Comment: maybe they have a pirated version of windows 10

Comment: 64bit versions of windows lack the WIN16 layer necessary to run 16bit applications due to issues with `HANDLE` size (basically it would remove the entire point of having a 64bit machine)

Comment: Is it? "%1" is unlikely to be the name of a program. The message says "not a win32" application, that doesn't mean its a 16 bit application it just means what it says which is it isn't a valid windows application. I doubt the version of GCC compiles 16-bit programs accidentally.

Comment: @Ahsanfarooq Was this actually the correct answer? Marie is not handling this question properly at all.